# Как сделать, чтобы содержимое атрибута placeholder отображалось по середине текстового поля input?

Tags: css3, html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы содержимое атрибута placeholder отображалось по середине текстового поля input, а не прижималось к левому краю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ueqz/

http://jsfiddle.net/nrJZ6/ - со скриптом для safari

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы текст вводился слева, а не по центру, при этом `placeholder` оставался посередине?

Comment: вот так - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/doymd7jt/

Comment: к сожалению, в сафари жмется к левому краю.. http://s014.radikal.ru/i326/1510/6b/a32199a8521a.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zh2vkvne/ - вот такой вариант работает

Comment: а вот так - да, круто - получается универсально! спасибо, @soledar10

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить такие стили

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
text-align:center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align:center; 
}
```

Тогда placeholder будет располагаться по центру инпута, а вводимый текст - позиционироваться по левому краю 
http://jsfiddle.net/5Ueqz/1/

Comment: для сафари не работает..